# Setting Network Credentials for Simple WebRequest

Tags: c#, https

Relatively new to C#, but making good progress.

I'm currently trying to test a System.Net.WebRequest method.  Using the useful http testing kit at https://httpbin.org/ - I am trying to pass network credentials to https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd and to retrieve a successful connection. (Currently getting 401's)

The username is user, and the password is passwrd.

I have a simple form, and button which starts the request.  However, as stated, its not working, and i'm getting a 401 error.

Here is what I have so far:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential(
        "user", "passwrd", "https://httpbin.org");


        // Create a request for the URL. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(
          "https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd");
        // If required by the server, set the credentials.
        request.Credentials = myCred;
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams and the response.
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Password is `passwd` not `passwrd`...

Comment: Haha!  That's a good start!  -  I'm still getting the error though.

Comment: I don't think domain looks like that : "https://httpbin.org". It must be something like "MYDOMAIN\myusername"

Comment: Try the `NetworkCredentials` without a host parameter. Also try `req.CachePolicy = new..(NoCacheNoStore);` to make sure you're really getting a non cached response from your previous attempts.

Comment: Thank you SimpleVar.  Removing the domain worked for me, and I now receive a success message.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your credentials, you are assuming that `domain` is the HTTP domain, but that's only useful for something like Active Directory domains. Just remove that parameter (and fix the password) and it will work:

```
NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential("user", "passwd");
```